# Kendo multi select dropdown not showing values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik

I tried using an example to bind values to Kendo multi select dropdown but unable to show data in dropdown list.

[Tried to use this example in Kendo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/angular)

[My trails are here](http://dojo.telerik.com/eTENI/2)

```
<div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
    <div class="demo-section k-content" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        {{selectOptions}}
        <h4>Select product</h4>
        <select kendo-multi-select k-options="selectOptions" k-ng-model="selectedIds"></select>
        <p ng-show="selectedIds.length" style="padding-top: 1em;">Selected: {{ selectedIds }}</p>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ])
    .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
        $scope.selectOptions = ['abc','def'];        
        $scope.selectedIds = [ 4, 7 ];
      })
</script>
```

Comment: I think you need to check the demo a bit more closely. `k-options` is not the array of options to display in the multiselect, it is an options object that, among other things, tells the multiselect how to get the options to display (that is the `dataSource` part).

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I am using kendoUI multiselect

```
<select kendo-multi-select k-options="selectOptions" k-ng-model="selectedIds" required></select>


$scope.selectOptions = {
                placeholder: "Select DimLinks...",
                dataTextField: "LINK_NAME",
                dataValueField: "PK_DIM_LINK",
                valuePrimitive: true,
                autoBind: false,
                dataSource: {
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "api/DimLinks",
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            $scope.selectedIds = [4, 7];
```

See if this helps.

Comment: how can I give static values as data source instead of reading from api?

Comment: change datasource like this-  dataSource: [
            "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"
            ]

Comment: Did some more research and came to some point. My edited code is at http://dojo.telerik.com/eTENI/3

Answer (score 0):

I did more research and tried many options and came to some point where I am able to show items. 
Hope this will be useful to other who is searching for similar solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/angular">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
    <div class="demo-section k-content" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

        <h4>Select Names</h4>


      <select id="name" kendo-multi-select ng-model="data.names" k-data-source="IDSAPIFieldsDataSource" k-option-label="{name: 'Name'}" k-options="nameOptions" style="width:200px"></select>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ])
    .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){        
      $scope.IDSAPIFieldsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: [{ name: 'Abc' }, { name: 'Def' }]
      });

            $scope.nameOptions = {
      placeholder: "Select",
      dataSource: $scope.IDSAPIFieldsDataSource ,
      dataTextField: "name",
      dataValueField: "name",
      valuePrimitive: true,
      autoBind: false
            }  
      })
</script>


</body>
</html>
```